# Wifi router configuration to enable P2P telnet?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, telnet

I have two computers connected via the wifi-router. (D-link DIR-615). One happens to be running windows 8.1. The other happens to be Ubuntu 16.04. I have enabled telnet service on windows, and disabled the firewall on the same os too. From the ubuntu box when I try to telnet the windows machine, I always get a timeout.

I am able to do some networking like http, rdp, via the two machines. I usually do ssh to the ubuntu box from windows. I even installed telnet service on ubuntu and tried to telnet to it from windows. That didn't work either.

Do we have to do anything in the router to enable this?

Comment: You want remote console terminal from Ubuntu to Windows?

Comment: Telnet is not secure, especially with disabled firewall. Highly recommend to use crypted one, ssh for example

Comment: Do you have a telnet server running on either machine?

Comment: You need a telnet server running on one machine to be able to connect to it from another. For Windows take a look at http://www.freesshd.com/

Comment: Check your wifi for a setting called "AP Isolation" or "Client Isolation", but since you say you can already connect via other protocols, the issue is not likely anything to do with the router at all. As for your detractors, it doesn't really matter whether telnet is secure, as long as its only moving between two machines on your LAN. perhaps a wifi intruder could sniff your traffic, but thats pretty unlikely unless you live in a densely packed area, or have enemies... ;-)

Comment: @FrankThomas it's bad practise, that can become a habit. Security isn't so difficult to implement, but can help. Also there may be viruses

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков, don't be silly. Does your router have a CA issued HTTPS certificate for accessing the web-console inside your LAN? accepting Self signed certs could be a bad habit. And if you have a sufficiently sophisticated worm already on a 2-machine LAN, then it getting your password by sniffing telnet traffic is the least of your problems, seeing as the infected system is either the one sending your password, or the one receiving it. Security is a spectrum, and any point you are at is either "safe enough" or not.

Comment: @FrankThomas Not router, end user. SSH remembers RSA key once, and alerts if its changed

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков  - What does any of this have to do with how the author enables Telnet though?  Given that ssh can be attacked also, if RSA key authentication isn't used, your argument against Telnet isn't logical.  Key authentication isn't appropriate for everyone in every environment  An intranet only Telnet/SSH server cannot be attacked from  outside of the network